# Configure TinyMCE for use of Font Awesome icons in Composite C1

Tags: tinymce, c1-cms

I use Composite C1 CMS, but the custom TinyMCE in it is so crazy. Simple issue: we'd like to use Font Awesome icons. Source code editing is OK.
If we add the following:

```
<i class="fa fa-bus"></i>
```

This is removed. OK then, add a space:

```
<i class="fa fa-bus">&#160;</i>
```

**i** is converted to **em**.

If I change **valid_elements** in config in the file visualeditor.js, nothing happens, still the same problem.

Are there any solution for this issue? Anyway it would be nice to add a button to the toolbar '*add icon*'.

Answer (score 16):

TinyMCE will remove empty elements by default, so you add a `&nbsp;` between your tags to tell the TinyMCE it's not empty. Also `<i>` used to be Italic in older versions of HTML so it's trying to convert an old italic tag into a preferred `<em>` Emphasis tag. Really though, you can use any tag with Font Awesome so to fix this issue, just change your `<i>` to a `<span>`:

`<span class="fa fa-bus">&nbsp;</span>`

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer uses `&nbsp;`, but this will create a gap next to your icon causing it to be slightly offset. A better alternative is to use a comment:

```html
<i class="fa fa-bus"><!-- icon --></i>
```

Now TinyMCE won't cleanup the "empty" element and you won't have a gap, but it will still convert your `<i>` to `<em>`. To prevent this, add the following to your TinyMCE init:

```js
tinymce.init({
  // ...
  extended_valid_elements: 'i[class]'
});
```

### TinyMCE Icon Fonts Plugin

The icon font dilemma has been a problem for years, so [I finally wrote a plugin](https://github.com/claviska/tinymce-iconfonts) to solve it with minimal effort. The plugin:

- Prevents TinyMCE from converting  icons into  elements
- Prevents TinyMCE from removing empty icons
- Makes icons selectable so you can copy/paste/delete them easier
- Let's you configure the CSS selector used to identify icons font elements

If you don't want to use the plugin, feel free to dive into [the source](https://github.com/claviska/tinymce-iconfonts/blob/master/src/plugin.js) to see exactly what's going on under the hood.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question but I want to add my two cents here.

As we all know, TinyMce strips out `<i></i>` so we have to find a way to bypass this problem.
A fast way I use in such cases is to replace `<i></i>` with `<span></span>` as Howdy_McGee mentioned before me.

So, to summarize, in your example instead of using:

`<i class="fa fa-bus"></i>`

you can just use:

`<span class="fa fa-bus">&nbsp;</span>`.