# List Icons: TinyMCE removes Font Awesome-Tags

Tags: css, list, icons, tinymce, font-awesome

**Font Awesome** supports [List Icons](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#list), which looks pretty nice and which is easy to handle and to setup. Example:

```
<ul class="fa-ul">
<li><i class="fa-li fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Point 1</li>
<li><i class="fa-li fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Point 2</li>
<li><i class="fa-li fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Point 3</li>
</ul>
```

That will look like this:

[image]

The Problem is the [**TinyMCE-Editor**](https://www.tinymce.com), which deletes unknown/unnecessary code and here the "empty" `<i>`-Snippet:

```
<i class="fa-li fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>
```

I know, there are the options *cleanup* and *verify_html* to disallow cleaning up the inserted code.

```
  tinymce.init({
    cleanup : false,
    verify_html : false
  });
```

This works, but it's quite complicated, nearly to impossible to edit after that the unordered lists in the TinyMCE-Editor. If I delete "Point 1" or overwrite the text, TinyMCE will also delete the `<i>`-Tag before (even if I'm still in the `<li>`-line). Basically there are two spaces before "Point 1". But this is hard to explain my customers.

Is there a solution or a tiny hack for this to prevent deleting the snippet in the editor? In my case every List-Point has the formation with the Icon. So it's okay to ADD ALWAYS the `<i>`-Tag after `<li>`. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure TinyMCE for use of Font Awesome icons in Composite C1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732501/configure-tinymce-for-use-of-font-awesome-icons-in-composite-c1)

Answer (score 2):

You could add a space so the tag is not empty:

```
<i class="fa-li fa fa-dot-circle-o">&nbsp;</i>
```

but it would change `<i>` to `<em>`

Answer (score 2):

This font icon problem has plagued me for a long time. I finally came up with a way to prevent it from happening, but it's not exactly a simple fix, so I wrapped it up into a plugin for TinyMCE 4 and 5:

https://github.com/claviska/tinymce-iconfonts

The plugin:

- Prevents TinyMCE from converting  icons into  elements
- Prevents TinyMCE from removing empty font icons
- Makes font icons selectable so you can copy/paste/delete them easier
- Let's you configure the CSS selector used to identify font icons

If you don't want to use it as a plugin, you're welcome to grab the relevant parts of [the source](https://github.com/claviska/tinymce-iconfonts/blob/master/src/plugin.js) and implement it manually.